# Dynamically adding post at the site using Observables (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I need to display posts dynamically on my home page. I have textarea above the post lists and my goal is to display new post immediatelly after it would be added, on the top of the post list. Component with textarea form is called `add-post-component` and it use `onSubmit` event:

```
onAddPostSubmit() {
        if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
            const post = {
                content: this.content,
                creator_username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).username,
                rate: 0
            };
            this.postsService.addPost(post).subscribe(data => {
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log('Post added');
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                } else {
                    console.log('Post not added' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Not logged');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Component of my main page is called Feed-component

```
this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(response => {
            this.posts = response.posts.reverse();
        }),
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        };

        this.subscription = this.postsService.fetchPost().subscribe(post => {
            this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(response => {
                    this.posts = response.posts.reverse();
            }),
            err => {
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            };
        });
```

Both components use posts service:

```
getPosts() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/fetch', {headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    addPost(post) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.subject.next({post});
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/posts/add', post, {headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    fetchPost(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
```

As you can see, I use Observable methodology to process data between components. The problem which I have is that post list is updating after I add post to database, but without the last added post. So if I would add two posts - 1) 'abc' and 2) 'cba', after send 'abc' anything happened, and when I add 'cba' list will be updated with 'abc' on the top.

I think the case is that `addPost` method is calling after `getPosts` and `fetchPost`.
How to fix that?

Comment: Does this means you want a real time update, seeing data on UI whenever you add without refreshing the particular page?

Comment: Yes, that's my points of view

Comment: I think you need to use Redux State Management- NGrx Store implementation for angular. It handles that pretty well ( https://github.com/ngrx/store ).

Comment: Can you please provide a working demo on stackblitz or any angular online editor ?